# How to simulate survival data

Tags: r

[image: AFT model for survial time and Cox model for censored time]

How can I generate survival data according to the specified models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating $\tilde{T}$ is straightforward from the model. I assume the difficulty lies in sampling $C$ from a Cox model, and you wouldn't be alone in this confusion.

The general methodology used to generate data from a Cox model is [inverse CDF sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) (the inverse operation of [probability integral transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform)). The sampling scheme goes as follows:

1. Generate $u \sim U(0,1)$ where $U(0,1)$ indicates the standard uniform distribution.
2. Set $c \gets F_C^{-1}(u)$ where $F_C$ is the cumulative distribution function of the censored time $C$.

I'll write the expression inside the exponential function as $h(X,A)$ for convenience. Then the Cox model has the hazard function $\lambda_C(t\mid X,A) = \lambda_0(t)\exp(h(X,A))$, which gives the survival function $S_C(t\mid X,A) = \exp\{-\Lambda_0(t)\exp(h(X,A)) \}$. The CDF and survival function are related to each other: $F_C(t\mid X,A) = 1-S_C(t\mid X,A)$.

Depending on the form of the cumulative hazard $\Lambda_0(t)$, the inverse of $F_C(t\mid X,A)$ may not be available in closed form. If $\Lambda_0^{-1}(x)$ is available, then $F_C^{-1}(u\mid X,A) = \Lambda^{-1}\left[-\log(1-u)\exp(h(X,A)) \right]$. If not, you may want to numerically solve the equation $F_C(t\mid X,A)-u=0$ for $t$ given a uniform variable $u$.

Comment: Thanks for your careful illustration, I'll try it out in this way~

Comment: Another question is that how I can control the censoring rate? For example, 50% censoring rate means that about half `C` should be no greater than `T`?

Comment: @BobChan That’s by construction not solvable since you are asking to figure out a mapping from the marginal censoring rate $r\%$ to a vector $\beta$, i.e., $r \mapsto \beta$. I would suggest that you play around with one of the $\beta_j$s and see if there is a monotonic relationship with the censoring rate, but there is no guarantee.